# Page Navigation Error WP RT

Tags: c#, debugging, windows-runtime

Everytime I press the back button to go from second page to main page I get this debugger error:

```
UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            };
```

my back button pressed event is this:

```
 private void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
        {
            Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

            if (rootFrame != null && rootFrame.CanGoBack)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                rootFrame.GoBack();
            }
        }
```

in my MainPage I inicializate a camera using a `<CaptureElement>` and when I press the button, I also get this error: `The requet is invalid in the current state` in this part of the code:

```
await _mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(imgProp, stream);
```

Comment: Could you specity what kind of Exception you get? Check the `e` parameter when debugging.

Comment: Is it a software or hardware button?

Comment: @Támas Deme this is the Exception:  e.Exception {System.Exception: The request is invalid in the current state at Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(ImageEncodingProperties type, IRandomAccessStream stream)   at Barcode_QRCode.MainPage.<ScanQrCode>d__a.MoveNext().

Comment: @Faisal  it is a  hardware button, the windows phone back button

Comment: @JoséAugustoAcorsi well, it seems like that you don't close or stop an async operation before leaving the page - please check if the object mentioned in the exception has a method for stop/dispose etc...

Comment: @TamásDeme I do this before navigate to next page `await _mediaCapture.StopPreviewAsync();` would this be stopping the async?

Comment: It should - but there could be more to it I guess - never done mediacapture before :\